# Have a form_for with a value that may be nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Users have favorite foods. I have a form on my user's page which lets users enter their favorite food:

However, if the user does not have a favorite_food, I get the error `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` and it highlights `@user.favorite_food`.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: can you post your form code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form), you need to provide an `ActiveRecord Object` in the `form_for` builder. If you don't have any value yet, you need to supply a `new` ActiveRecord Object, which is typically done by defining `Model.new`:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def new
    @object = Model.new
end

#app/views/controller/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @object do |f| %>
```

However, I have just learnt that you can supply a symbol to the form:

```
#app/views/controller/new.html.erb
<%= form_for :object do |f| %>
```

I appreciate this answer is rather broad. If you supply some code, I can amend it to fix to align with your requirements

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue when using nested attributes - where has_one or has_many relation exists. My example was "hospital" has_one "contact_detail", and the form was failing if there was no ContactDetail object. To resolve this, I had to build a child object before rendering the forms.

Something like -

```
@hospital = Hospital.new
@hopital.build_contact_detail   # Name of the association is contact_detail
```

In your case, I think you should do something like:

```
@user.build_favorite_food  # Favorite food being name of association
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Both answers already posted are correct, although they are not complete. For it to work for both an `@user` that has a `favourite_food` and one that doesn't, your form needs to do something like this:

```
<%= form_for (@user.favourite_food || @user.build_favourite_food) do |f| %>
```

This way, if the user has a favourite food, the form will be automatically and properly filled with the attributes. If the user doesn't, then it will create a new one.

Another good practise is to isolate that logic in a FormHelper.

Hope this was helpful.